# How to mod_rewrite / to /frontend/index.html?

Tags: apache

I am trying to host both a PHP API and a static/built Angular app on a single Apache server (hosted by SiteGround.com).

Right now I've got this .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !frontend/
RewriteRule ^$ /index.html
RewriteRule ^/$ /index.html
RewriteRule (.*) /frontend/$1 [L]
```

I assumed the `^$` and `^/$` rules would be enough to make the root of `mysite.com` to transparently serve `/frontend/index.html` but i just get a 200 OK response with no content when i browse to `mysite.com`; however `mysite.com/index.html` does show my Angular app. I also tried escaping the rule with `^\/$` but that didn't work either.

I also tried making the root rules have higher priority but that didn't work

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^$ /frontend/index.html [L]
RewriteRule ^\/$ /frontend/index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^app.apprevenir.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !frontend/
RewriteRule (.*) /frontend/$1 [L]
```

What's missing from my .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the rules worked, but SiteGround's NGinx cache was causing the site to ultimately not react to the changed rules.